# How to use custom Objective-C object in C++?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I'm implementing some fast sort algorithms, and to get best performances, I'd like to use a C++ binding in Objective-C. But I want my algorithms to work with user custom objects and with something similar to a NSComparator ; which type may I use in C++ to use these objects ? May I template a class ?

Please let me know about your best solution to bind custom objects in C++ and to use a NSComparator in C++ ?

Best regards,

Hervé HL.

Comment: You can't have both the speed of statically typed and the flexibility of dynamically typed. Fastest solution is to use a template and some overloaded comparison function. Second-fastest is to send a function pointer to a bog-standard C function. You might also want to use a macro (there's a nice QSORT-as-a-macro floating around which gives very good performance)

Comment: Ok, I was expecting I could only move pointers in C++, no matter what kind of object are located into each memory fragment (custom object or not). A C++ implementation does not appear to be the right solution to keep flexivity, will do this in Objective-C directly!
Thanks for your reply @Dave!

Comment: You can. But the issue is being able to call the comparison function. For example, you could reverse the list no problem.

Comment: With Objective-C++, I found a solution to pass a NSComparator and use it in my C++ methods. Will post the code asap! Thanks @Dave.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Dave, I finally found the solution to extract pointers from NSArray, no matter the contained type, do some complex operations, and then reassemble the pointers, using *void ** type.

Just rename your .m file to .mm to enable Objective-C++ features.

```
void *array[[self count]]; //create an empty void* array
for (uint i = 0; i < [self count]; i++)
{
    int address = (int)[self objectAtIndex:i];
    array[i] = (void *)address; //insert NSObjects pointers into void* array
}
```

To get back the NSObjects from void* array, just proceed like this:

```
NSMutableArray *doneAr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //create a NSMutableArray
for (uint i = 0; i < [self count]; i++)
{
    void *tmp = (void **)done + i; //extract the pointer in the void* array
    NSString *strTmp = (NSString *)(*((Class *)tmp)); //convert it back to origin type (here NSString *)
    [doneAr addObject:strTmp]; //add it back to the previously created NSMutableArray
}
```

Hope this answer could be helpful for future issues. If you wish to use NSComparator like me in your C++ implementation, just rename your .m file into .mm file so as you can use Objective-C++ features ; then import  and use what you need (NSComparator for example).

Comment: This code is valid (if a little odd in places), but as I said in my first comment, it's the *comparisons* that will be difficult. When sorting, you need to know what type the objects are and call an appropriate comparison function for various pairs of elements, whereas in this code you've lost that information. The best you could hope for is to sort according to a set type (here you seem to be assuming it will only ever run on `NSString`) or by memory address. And unless you can somehow remove all Objective C calls from your comparison function, I'm afraid it will not have the speed of C++.

Comment: Indeed you're right. It's possible but the high numbers of conversions would make the sort slower than it could be using C++. Will continue to look for a way to perform such an operation, and keep this subject up-to-date!